# Ruby on Rails - RESTful API Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, authentication

Im building a simple REST API with ruby on rails that allows users to easily create an account.  Recently I have tried to secure the API with an API token.  I have been testing my API with the `Advanced Rest Client` that is found on the Google chrome web store.  As far as I know it has worked as when I try to access the calls I get a message from my REST client test application that looks like this:

[image]

The problem comes when I try to authenticate successfully with the `Advanced Rest Client`.  Here is the controller code that I use to create the token and check to see if the user authenticated:

```
class Api::UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  TOKEN = "secret"
  before_action :authenticate

  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new()
    @user.first_name = params[:first_name]
    @user.last_name = params[:last_name]
    @user.email = params[:email]
    @user.password = params[:password]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        @response = {:status => "201", :message => "User successfully created."}
        format.json { render json: @response, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  # private methods in the UserController class
  private

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      token == TOKEN
    end
  end
end
```

It's fairly simple and seems to be doing its job as I haven't been able to authenticate with the `Advanced Rest Client`.  I have tried to set an API token in the HTTP headers but can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Here are a few examples of what I have tried:

[image]

and,

[image]

and finally,

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is the API token not stored in a HTTP header?  Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header is incorrect, the key should be `Authorization`

Try putting this as the Raw header:

`Authorization: Token token=secret`

Comment: thank you that seemed to work I just had to put secret in `""` the final line was `Authorization: Token token="secret"`

Comment: I think I am going to use a UDID for the actual key.  Is there a more secure way to do this, something that doesn't have the API key hardcoded into every single controller I use for the API? What is best practice for something like this in rails? @Simon

Comment: @ScottOBot yea I'd generate a token per user/account using something like `SecureRandom.hex`. This is a good post about best practices: http://blog.envylabs.com/post/75521798481/token-based-authentication-in-rails